# How to get the current foreground application in electron(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, windows, process, window, electron

How can I detect if, for example, a browser is currently open?
I need this in my electron-application. 
ty :)

I've found nothing like this online.
I've only found how I can check which window is open from the windows I have in my own application, but I need to know, what else is opened.

It should be something like this:

```
if(Application.isOpen('Google Chrome'){}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless someone has built a specific electron api to do this (which I can't find), then from electron...no. However, the beauty of electron being built with node.js, means that any node module should be able to do the job for you.

For example, [ps-list](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ps-list) should be able to get you all currently running processes.

```
psList().then(processes => {
  console.log(processes)
})
```

Which gives a list for me, including:

[image: chrome process]

Just be aware that you need node access from the electron thread attempting to use this lib.

This can easily be abstracted to do a name search in the list for you to get your desired functionality.

Comment: Is there any event if another app has been closed or opened ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find-process](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-process) in case you need to search by given name, name pattern or pid.